# How can I create multiple instances of a class without defining them?

Tags: javascript

So, I'm making a game on HTML5 canvas. It's a top down shooter, and I need to create a bullet every time you click to make the character shoot.

Initially, I just prevented the player from firing another bullet until it went out of bounds or it hit an enemy, as seen here. This worked percetly, but of course, makes for uninteresting gameplay.

Then, I began researching about JS classes, and I thought that it would be the key to the problem. I created a bullet class, and moved all the logic for the bullet to the class. Then, I created an instance of it, and called it in other parts of the code to execute its logic. This worked exactly as it did before, which is good, because it meant I could translate the thing I had before to a class, but it had a similar issue.

This is how the class is defined:

```
class bullet{

    constructor(_img, _piercing){

        this.bulletPic = document.createElement("img");
        this.img = this.bulletPic.src = _img;
        this.piercing = _piercing;
    }

    shoot(){
        this.bulletAngle = playerAngle;
        this.bulletX = playerX;
        this.bulletY = playerY;
        bulletShot = true;
        shots = 0;
    }

    draw(){
        canvasContext.save();
        canvasContext.translate(this.bulletX, this.bulletY);
        canvasContext.rotate(this.bulletAngle);
        canvasContext.drawImage(this.bulletPic, -this.bulletPic.width / 2, -this.bulletPic.height / 2);
        canvasContext.restore();

        if(bulletShot){
            this.bulletX += Math.sin(this.bulletAngle) * BULLET_SPEED;
            this.bulletY -= Math.cos(this.bulletAngle) * BULLET_SPEED;
        }

    }
}
```

And here is the object definition:

```
let bullet1 = new bullet("Textures/player.png", true);
```

If I want to shoot another bullet at the same time, I need to have already defined a new instance of the bullet class, is there any way for me to define a new instance every time I click?

Edit: The shoot and draw methods are called in another file that follow logic that's not shown here. Mainly what this other code does, is detect when it hits an enemy or when it goes out of bounds to set "bulletShot" to false, that makes it "despawn", and I can shoot another bullet. This is part of the 1 bullet at a time limitation I'm trying to remove here, but that can go once this central issue is fixed.

Comment: The placement of `if(shots >= 1 && ammo >= 0){` seems syntactically wrong. Should it not be placed inside some method?

Comment: @trincot hmm yeah, I just realized that I pasted the code that I was doing tests with, hold on, let me edit it.

Comment: I agree - it should be inside the `shoot` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making an array that contains multiple instances of the class. I defined a variable that I used as a limit and then set up a for statement to create all the objects, then, I can call them using the array name and the position.

```
for(var i = 0; i < arraySize; i++){
    arrayName[i] = new className(parameters);
}
```

Examples of usage:

```
arrayName[5].method();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your situation, you could use a function that returns a new class:

```
function bulletFactory( className ) {
    return new className();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I fail to understand how could this help. I need a new instance of the class to be created on the go, meaning, while the game is running. Defining instances beforehand won't work because that limits the ammount of bullets I can shoot.

Comment: Your question is "is there any way for me to define a new instance every time I click?", if you add this function to an `onClick`, it would return a new instance of `bullet`.

Comment: Ok, I'll play with it for a bit and try it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve that there could be several bullets in "mid-air", after a series of fast consecutive clicks, then create an array of bullets. You would initialise that array like this:

```
const bullets = Array({length: ammo}, () => new Bullet());
```

`ammo` would be the number of bullets that the user can shoot in total.

NB: I simplified the call of the constructor. Add the arguments you want to pass. Secondly, it is common practice to start class names with a capital.

Then add a state property in the Bullet instances that indicates whether the bullet is:

- Hidden: it is not visible yet, but part of the total ammunition that can still be used in the future
- Ready: it is the one bullet that is visible at the start location, ready to be fired by the user
- Shot: a bullet that has been shot and is currently flying through the game area

At first this state is "hidden":

```
constructor(_img, _piercing){
    this.state = "hidden";
    // ...
}
draw() {
    if (this.state === "hidden") return; // Don't draw bullets that are not available
    // ...
}
```

Then at the start of the game, make one bullet visible (where it should be clicked):

```
bullets[0].state = "ready"; // From now on it will be drawn when `draw()` is called
```

In the click handler do the following:

```
// Fire the bullet the user clicked on:
bullets.find(bullet => bullet.state === "ready").shoot(playerAngle, playerX, playerY);
// See if there is a next bullet remaining in the user's ammo:
const nextBullet = bullets.find(bullet => bullet.state === "hidden");
if (nextBullet) nextBullet.state = "ready"; // Otherwise ammo is depleted.
```

The `shoot` method should not rely on global variables, but get the necessary external info as arguments:

```
shoot(playerAngle, playerX, playerY) {
    this.bulletAngle = playerAngle;
    this.bulletX = playerX;
    this.bulletY = playerY;
    this.state = "shot";
}
```

Don't use global variables inside your class methods (`shot`, `ammo`,...). Instead use arguments or other instance properties.

The `draw` method should also work with that `state`:

```
draw() {
    if (this.state === "hidden") return; // Don't draw bullets that are not available
    // ...
    if(this.state === "shot") {
        this.bulletX += Math.sin(this.bulletAngle) * BULLET_SPEED;
        this.bulletY -= Math.cos(this.bulletAngle) * BULLET_SPEED;
    }
}
```

In your animation loop, you should call `draw` on all bullets. Something like:

```
bullets.forEach(bullet => bullet.draw());
```

I did not see any code for when a bullet has left the game area, either by hitting something or just flying out of range. In such case the bullet should be removed from the `bullets` array to avoid that the `draw` method keeps drawing things without (visual) significance.

Here is how you could delete a specific bullet:

```
function deleteBullet(bullet) {
     const i = bullets.indexOf(bullet);
     if (i > -1) bullets.splice(i, 1);
}
```

I hope this gets you going on your project.

Comment: I'll need a couple of coffees to understand all that, but I get where you are going. I'll see how I can adapt this, thanks.